# Command line argv not showing up during debugging (using github codespace)

Tags: c, parameters, command-line-arguments, cs50, argv

when I input debug50 Caeser 1024 into my code space argc shows as 2 which is correct but argv shows as 0x7ffd87a68798
[as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EnWz.png) and idk why it doesn't show as 1024?

this is the first time I've used command line arguments so would appreciate any help, please.

This is my code so far also would appreciate any checks on my function I think that's wrong as well :/

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

bool only_digit(string argv[1]);


int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    //Make sure program was run with command line argument (argc)

    if (argc == 2){
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }

    }
    //Make sure every character in argv[1] is a number

     bool only_digit(string argv[1]){

        if (isdigit((*argv[1]))){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
     }
```

Comment: If you invoke the program with one argument, then the condition `argc == 2` is true, and the program returns immediately.

Comment: And the `only_digit` function doesn't make sense, why should it take an *array* of strings as arguments, if it's supposed to check one single string? And where's the loop to check all the characters?

Comment: "why it doesn't show as 1024?" Why would it? It is an array of pointers. You are looking at the address of the first pointer, not at the string where it points to.

Comment: And one of the major problems with the CS50 course, IMO, is that it hides what strings in C really are. The type`string` is really an alias for `char *`. It's a *pointer* (to the first character in the string).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I don't really understand what u mean by the first part " invoking the program with one argument" also thanks for the help with the loop i was unsure if just using (isdigit((*argv[1]))) would just check if all the characters in the array were string but obviously I was wrong.

Comment: The value of `argc` is the number of valid elements in the `argv` array. If you don't pass any command-line arguments to the program, then `argc == 1`. If you pass one command-line argument to the program then `argc == 2`. See how you exit the program if that condition is true?

Comment: thank u @Gerhardh I was completely unaware that it was the address to the pointer and not a string that clears a lot up thanks again.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude in the question in CS50 it tells you to check that the user inputs 2 valid elements and then to return 0 but it then asks you to check if argv is made up of digits my main confusion is when i return 0 it exits the loop how do i check argv please

Comment: If  `argc` is ***not*** equal to `2`, print the error message and return. Otherwise continue with the rest of the program.

Comment: If you are requested to return 0 in case you got correct number of arguments, that does not mean you need to return immediately. That just defined what value you shall return. You still have to do your job first. For error returns that is different. There is not job to do if you don't get proper input data.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if no. of arguments doesn't match what you expect first and return if it doesn't.

Also, you should learn how to declare/define functions properly with arguments. `argv[1]` means you are expecting an array of strings of size 1.

Also, your function can be a single return statement.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

bool only_digit(string s);

int main(int argc, string argv[]) {
    // Make sure program was run with command line argument (argc)

    if (argc != 2)  {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("%d\n", only_digit(argv[1]));
}
// Make sure every character in argv[1] is a number

bool only_digit(string s) {
    return isdigit(*s);
}
```

Comment: Firstly thank you for your help but it seems after implementing your suggestion about declaring/defining functions properly and then implementing a loop that checks for digits in the string which returns a bool and then depending on the answer prints a message I have further confused myself I would really appreciate some insight to where I've gone wrong.

Comment: You immediately return if `argc == 2`. You shouldn't return there, but instead call `only_digit()` before return.